# Is it possible to use PAF for mobile testing

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Is it possible to perform mobile testing using Pace Automation Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use PAF for Mobile Testing. Both IOS and Android testing  can be done using PAF.